# Why I get a QmlCachedGenerateCode when I tried to create a new qml file?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I tried to create a new qml file in my project, but when I run it shows me an error message "undefined reference to QmlCachedGeneratedCode", but I checked and the file that I created was added in the qml.qrc file, I don know how to fix this error, I tried clean my project, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I run git clean -f to clean the cache, but it still does't working, so I clone again the repository and it works, I don't know why.